# diffrent elements from diffrent elements

Tags: nuclear-physics, elements

Do we get elements from other elements ?

Somebody said they believed the world was visited by aliens and they made slavs of us and then amde us mine gold for them then they leave us to grow into what we no as humanity today.

I said it would be easier for them to make the gold if they can make space ships and travel thru space,and i said that we make elements from other elements all the time,i even said the sun takes elements and changes them and bombards us all the time with the new elements.

i got the answer back off a self proclaimed astro- no it all scientist geologist brain box ---we need the power of a star to do this and its not so common on earth--i cited the hadron colider as making diffrent elemenst from the 1s it used.i even put plutonium 238 and the break down of it as it goes back to lead.

whose right?>

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways something can change from one element to another.  Particle colliders are a good example, just like radioactive decay.  We do not have the capabilities to do this for large quantities of material, like what happens in the sun.